# GET group_id / feed with APP Access Token Error 200

Tags: facebook, api, graph, sdk

I'm cant GET Feeds of a Public Group where I'm the Admin.
The result is "(#200) Permissions error".

If I use an USER Access Token, The GET Work Ok, and obtain the list of feeds.

Please help me !!!!

Comment: You say it works if you use a user access token. What is the problem then?

Comment: I want use with a app token, not with user token

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: Wy? In this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/feed

said 

Permissions

- A User access token of an Admin of the Group with the user_managed_groups permission.

- An app access token can read posts it published in app and game groups that belong to it.

Comment: Is it an app and game group that the app created?

Comment: My Group of face is the type purchase sale, The App I choose the category shopping

Comment: So it is not an app and games group. So you have to use a user access token

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer and your time.

Answer (score 0):

The v2.12 update currently requires an admin user access token to read the group/feed endpoint among others. This is temporary and in the coming weeks it will return to allowing non-Admin permissions but restricting the amount of user information returned.

source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.12#gapi-90-groups

> GET /group — GET operations on the following fields and edges now require an access token of an Admin of the Group:
>
> [...]
>
> - GET /feed*
>
> [...]
>
> In the coming weeks, edges marked with an asterisk (*) will once again allow requests from non-Admin Group members. However, responses will not include User information unless the request is made with an access token of an Admin of the Group.